# Issue with Discord.js MongoDB Economy System

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I'm programming a basic Discord.js economy system with MongoDB and Mongoose, and I'm a beginner so I've run into an issue. I'm trying to add a Mongoose Schema that represents a job. It is a number, where 0 stands for no job, 1 stands for Doctor, 2 stands for Policeman, and 3 stands for Chef. Here's my code.

ProfileSchema.js (Where I create the schema)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: { type: String, require: true, unique: true},
    serverID: { type: String, require: true},
    coins: { type: Number, default: 500},
    bank: { type: Number},
    job: { type: Number, default: 0}
})

const model = mongoose.model('ProfileModels', profileSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

Here's the part of my message.js file that creates a profile for a member as soon as they send a message:

```
let profileData;
    try{
        profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id});
        if(!profileData){
            let profile = await profileModel.create({
                userID: message.author.id,
                serverID: message.guild.id,
                coins: 500,
                bank: 0,
                job: 0
            });
            profile.save()
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
```

Okay, we're almost done. Here's where you assign the jobs.

```
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
module.exports = {
    name: 'getjob',
    description: 'get a job',
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord, profileData) {
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`You need to select a job!`);
            
        }
        else if (args[0] === 'doctor') {
            return message.channel.send('You have selected the job: Doctor');
            const job = 1
        }
        else if (args[0] === 'policeman') {
            return message.channel.send('You have selected the job: Policeman);
            const job = 2
        }
        else if (args[0] === 'chef') {
            return message.channel.send('You have selected the job: Chef');
            const job = 3
        }
        const response = await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        
            {
                userID: message.author.id
            },
            {
                $inc: {
                    job: job,
                },
            }
        );
    
    }
}
```

Last block of code, I promise. Here's where I think it went wrong. I created a test command to see if the job was actually assigned, so it basically just tells you what job you have.

```
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
module.exports = {
    name: "jobtest",
    description: "jobtest",
    execute(client, message, args,  Discord, profileData){
        if (profileData = 0) return message.channel.send(`You are unemployed!`)
        if (profileData = 1) return message.channel.send(`You are a doctor.`)
        if (profileData = 2) return message.channel.send(`You are an policeman.`)
        if (profileData = 3) return message.channel.send(`You are a chef.`)


    }

}
```

Sorry for all that code. Basically, the issue is that when I run ?jobtest, no matter what job I am supposed to have, it always says "You are a doctor." Can someone tell me where I went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: in your final piece of code you are using a single `=` it should be `==` or `===` for conditions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your last block of code.

- '=' is used for assignment of a variable. Consider using '===' instead as it is used to check equality between variables.
- Use `profileData.job` instead of `profileData`.

````
module.exports = {
    name: "jobtest",
    description: "jobtest",
    execute(client, message, args,  Discord, profileData){
        if (profileData === 0) return message.channel.send(`You are unemployed!`)
        if (profileData === 1) return message.channel.send(`You are a doctor.`)
        if (profileData === 2) return message.channel.send(`You are an policeman.`)
        if (profileData === 3) return message.channel.send(`You are a chef.`)


    }

}```
````